# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'indexer'

Tags: spell-checking, indexer

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 from spellchecker import SpellChecker
2
3 spell = SpellChecker()
4 def correct_spellings(text):
5     corrected_text = []

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spellchecker/core.py in ()
24 import urllib
25
---> 26 from indexer import DictionaryIndex
27 from langdetect import _detect_lang
28

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'indexer'

---

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.`enter code here`

Comment: Hi! Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include the full source code you have as a minimal reproducible example, which can be compiled and tested by others :)

Answer (score 34):

You might have used this to install `pip install spellchecker`, install using `pip install pyspellchecker`.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me overcome my issue.